# Is it possible to filter the panels created in a dashboard using GRAFANA based on their name

Tags: grafana

I have created a dashboard in grafana having multiple status panels. I need to provide a dropdown such that when one option is selected all the panels having a name corresponding to the selected option will be filtered. So, basically i need to filter the panels based on their name.Is this possible. If yes, how can we go about it

Answer (score 1):

a bit late for an answer now I suppose but will answer you anyway. You can create filters in Grafana without the need for a plug in through using the Variables feature in your Dashboard settings. Its also used in templating to make your data more dynamic but also crucial in display when you want to filter. Check out the link below

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/reference/templating/

Comment: Is it possible to add a filter/variable to a single panel of a dashboard? Not the whole dashboard? If yes, how? Thank you!

Comment: @tonix yes. Its done the same way. You would just call the variable in the panel query. The only caveat is that you cannot place the specifc filter directly above the panel. ALL filters are placed at the top of the dashboard  and cannot moved to be directly above the panels they affect

Comment: This is all true but does not answer the original question of the poster which was not about using variables but filtering down a number of panels.

Answer (score 0):

The way to accomplish something like this is with [Grafana's Repeating Rows/Panels feature](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/add-panels-dynamically/about-repeating-panels-rows/).

Essentially, this lets you dynamically duplicate a row/panel for all the possible results of a given variable. Then a dashboard user can use the variable selection UI to drill down and only show certain rows or panels. Make sure you allow multi-select and/or `All` as an option for the variable(s) so that you can see multiple results at a time.